# quadratic formula when a and c are positive?

Tags: quadratics

How can you do the quadratic forumla when a and c are positive? I am in a calc class trying to find when the velocity is 0 with a given quadratic equation. But when a and c are positive you get a negative square root, no?

ex)

$$a= 4,\quad b= 3,\quad c= 5$$

$$b^2-4(4)(5)$$

$4 \cdot 4 \cdot 5$ will be positive.

$3$ minus a positive $=$ a negative.

but you can't do a square root of a negative?

Comment: Well, if those a,b,c values are indeed correct, that velocity ain't gonna be zero!

Comment: really? this was downvoted? lol ok.

Comment: The issue here is not that $a$ and $c$ are positive, but that $4ac>b^2$.

Comment: I did not downvote

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $c$ are both positive, then $b^2-4ac$ can be positive or negative.

If $4ac<b^2$ then $b^2-4ac$ is positive and, as you surely know, the equation has two roots.

Comment: ok well my a = 3, b = -24 and c= 45.

Comment: In this case $b^2=576$ and $4ac=540$. Then $b^2-4ac=36$, positive.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample:
$a=1,\,b = 5,\,c=2$

$b^2-4ac = 5^2-4\times1\times4 = 25-16 = 9 > 0$

Comment: @Omeed Why don't you provide us with the question? If you only give the a,b,c values, we can't compare

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that location is given by a quadratic polynomial and velocity by its derivative?  In that case, it's the derivative, not the original quadratic polynomial, that you would set equal to $0$.

Comment: I greatly suspect that's indeed what it is. Hence I asked him to provide us with the question...